# Select point on highcharts stock

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I can't seem to select a point on highcharts stock chart like I can with a normal chart. Bellow is my configuration:

```
function ChartConfigKpiSecSummary(params) {

    //------------------
    // Private variables
    //------------------

    //-----------------
    // Public variables
    //-----------------

    this.config = {

        chart: {
            height: 232,
            type: 'spline',
            events: {
                click: params.chartClick
            }
        },

        colors: [
            params.palette.kpi
        ],

        credits: {
            enabled: false // remove 'highcharts.com' credits label
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            align: 'right',
            itemMarginBottom: 15,
            layout: 'vertical',
            verticalAlign: 'top'
        },

        navigator: {
            height: 20,
            maskFill: 'rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.5)',
            series: {
                color: '#ffffff',
                lineWidth: 0
            },
            xAxis: {
                showFirstLabel: false,
                tickPixelInterval: 20000
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataGrouping: {
                    enabled: false // Prevent averaging of point values displayed in tooltips when graph width is collapsed
                }
            }
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [],

        title: null,

        tooltip: {
            crosshairs: true,
            formatter: function() {
                var retval = '';
                if (_channelAvailable(this.points, espCommonUtil.capitalizeFirstLetter(params.analytics.series[0].name))) {
                    retval += this.y.toFixed() + '% ' + this.points[0].series.name;
                }
                return retval;
            },
            shared: true
        },

        xAxis: {
            events: {
                afterSetExtremes: params.afterSetExtremes
            },
            minRange: 1,
            showFirstLabel: false
        },

        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            opposite: false,
            title: {
                style: {
                    fontSize: params.axisTitleSize
                },
                text: 'Percent'
            }
        }
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < params.analytics.series.length; i++) {
        this.config.series.push(
            {
                name: espCommonUtil.capitalizeFirstLetter(params.analytics.series[i].name),
                data: params.analytics.series[i].data
            }
        )
    }

    //------------------
    // Private functions
    //------------------

    function _channelAvailable(points, channelName) {

        var retval = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            if (points[i].series.name !== channelName) {
                continue;
            }

            retval = true;
            break;
        }

        return retval;
    }

    //---------------------
    // Privileged functions
    //---------------------
}
```

How do I configure this?

Comment: Please show sample on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Try to enable [allowPointSelect](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.allowPointSelect) parameter.